# Newlines and formatters

Tags: f#, string-formatting

I recently got bit by becoming complacent writing things like

```
printf "\n%f\n" 3.2
```

instead of

```
printf "%s%f%s" Environment.NewLine 3.2 Environment.NewLine
```

My question is: is there any way to write the safe second version as nicely as the first (i.e. a special character in the format string which inserts `Environment.Newline` so that an argument for each newline instance in the format string isn't required)?

Comment: When i tried with two trailing \n, it seems to get what you want. 
printf "\n%f\n\n" 3.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using kprintf for a double pass, replacing \n with NewLine:

```
let nprintf fmt = Printf.kprintf (fun s -> s.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine) |> printf "%s") fmt
```

Then in `nprintf "\n%f\n" 3.2` all \n get replaced by NewLine.

Comment: I like it! One thing I learned I need to be careful with using this solution is that every newline which goes into `s` must be represented using "\n".

Answer (score 8):

There's not an escape sequence, but you could shorten it:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module StringFormatting =
    let nl = System.Environment.NewLine

//Usage
printfn "%s%f%s" nl 3.2 nl
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829%28VS.100%29.aspx#Y407) is the list of character escapes on MSDN.

As an aside, I wonder what this would do:

```
printfn @"
%f
" 3.2
```